# Overlaying a canvas over an iframe - HTML

Tags: html, iframe, canvas, overlay, z-index

I'm busy writing a servlet that generates HTML code. The goal is to create a heatmap of where people click on a website from stored data of those clicks. I've found javascript to create the heatmap in a canvas, and i now want to overlay that canvas over the webpage that the click information is about.

This is my HTML so far, which results in the successful generation of the heatmap, and the creation of an iframe. The iframe is overlayed over the heatmap. Currently i dont know how to make the iframe the same size as the webpage so that it appears that the website is being viewed with the heatmap overlayed over it:

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <style> 
            #heatmapArea{
            position:relative;
            float:left;
            width:410px;
            height:410px;
                            z-index:1000;
            border:1px dashed black;

                    #iframeArea{
                            position:relative;
                            float:left;
                            width:100%;
                            height:100%
                            z-index:1;
                    }
        }
    </style> 
</head> 

<body> 
    <div id="main"> 
        <div id="heatmapArea"> 
                        <div id="iframeArea">
                            <iframe src="www.google.com"></iframe>
                        </div>

        </div> 
    </div> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="heatmap.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 


    window.onload = function(){
        var xx = h337.create({"element":document.getElementById("heatmapArea"), "radius":10, "visible":true});
        var el = "{max: 100, data: [{x: 20, y: 20, count: 10},{x: 200, y: 200, count: 43},{x: 200, y: 400, count: 7},{x: 380, y: 400, count: 6},{x: 400, y: 400, count: 4},{x: 280, y: 260, count: 100},{x: 80, y: 60, count: 40},{x: 166, y: 260, count: 85},{x: 300, y: 400, count: 34},]}";
        var obj = eval('('+el+')');
        xx.store.setDataSet(obj);
    };

    </script> 
</body>
```

im a serious HTML newbie - what can i do to make what i want happen?

thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand you want to do it in html and css. Then maybe:

**Step 1:**
Add this to your CSS: `html, body {height: 100%;}`

**Step 2**
Add this to your iframe class: `position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;`

I created a quick fiddle to show you, how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/a3muZ/

Comment: is there a way to make the page scroll down too if you scroll the iframe down? the problem is that if the iframe scrolls down, the context of the heatmap is lost. for instance:

Here is the initial page context, the heat map showing where people scrolled/zoomed: http://imgur.com/a/Uhljn#GgWJ6

When the actual page is scrolled down, the context is preserved: http://imgur.com/a/Uhljn#wwT2S

But when the iframe is scrolled, the heatmap doesn't follow the scroll and the context is lost: http://imgur.com/a/Uhljn#bhXSu

Comment: I might have understood wrong, but did you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/a3muZ/1/  This of course means positioning with top, right, bottom or left. But making it sticky on scroll: position: fixed;